# Передача указателя на массив между библиотеками c# и c++

Tags: c#, c++, указатели, dll

Я имею проект, написанный на c#, который передает указатель на массив в проект, написанный на c++. Я использую указатель на массив структур в c#, передаю его в метод проекта c++, где массив заполняется инициализированными структурами. Проблема в использовании указателя, после его обработки в библиотеке c++. 
приведу код c# проекта:

```
public unsafe struct surface
{
    public int id;
    public double * x;
    public double * y;
    public double * z;
    public int count;
};
public struct surface1
{
    public int Id;
    public double[] X;
    public double[] Y;
    public double[] Z;
    public int Count;
};

public class GRD_MBA
{
    private IntPtr _pGrdMba = IntPtr.Zero;

    [DllImport("GRD_MBA.dll")]
    private static extern unsafe void GetSurfaces(void** ppGrdMba, surface* list, int n);

    [DllImport("GRD_MBA.dll")]
    private static extern unsafe int GetCountSurfaces(void** ppGrdMba);

    [DllImport("GRD_MBA.dll")]
    private static extern unsafe int GetCountPointsSurface(void** ppGrdMba, int id);

   public unsafe List<surface1> GetSurfaces()
    {
        List<surface1> resList = new List<surface1>();
        fixed (void* ppGrdMba = &_pGrdMba)
        {
            int n = GetCountSurfaces((void**) ppGrdMba);
            surface [] resSurs = new surface[n];

            fixed (surface* s = &resSurs[0])
            {
                GetSurfaces((void**) ppGrdMba, s, n);
            }

            foreach (var sur in resSurs)
            {
                int count = GetCountPointsSurface((void**) ppGrdMba, sur.id);
                surface1 surface = new surface1
                {
                    Id = sur.id,
                    Count = count
                };

                double* x = &sur.x[0];
                double[] xx = new double[count];
                if ((IntPtr)x != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)x, xx, 0, count);
                surface.X = xx;

                double* y = &sur.y[0];
                double[] yy = new double[count];
                if ((IntPtr)y != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)y, yy, 0, count);
                surface.Y = yy;

                double* z = &sur.z[0];
                double[] zz = new double[count];
                if ((IntPtr)z != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)z, zz, 0, count);
                surface.Z= zz;
                resList.Add(surface);
            }
        }
        return resList;
    }    
}
```

А вот код из c++ проекта:

интересующая часть заголовочного файла:

```
#define BUILDGRID_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#include <windows.h>

struct mainRes
{
    ~mainRes();
    int id;
    int count;
    vector<double> x;
    vector<double> y;
    vector<double> z;   
};

BUILDGRID_API void __stdcall GetSurfaces(void** ppGrdMba, mainRes * list, int n);

BUILDGRID_API int __stdcall GetCountSurfaces(void** ppGrdMba);

BUILDGRID_API int __stdcall GetCountPointsSurface(void** ppGrdMba, int id);
```

часть файла с исходным кодом:

```
void GetSurfaces(void** ppGrdMba, mainRes * list, const int n)
{
    grid* gObj = static_cast<grid*>(*ppGrdMba);
    vector<mainRes> res = gObj->get_surfaces();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list[i] = res[i];
}
```

В этом методе происходит копирование данных из одного массива в другой. При компиляции все данные в массиве list правильные.

Я представила те методы, которые вызывают у меня подозрения. Большие сомнения обращены на метод GetSurfaces класса GRD_MBA проекта c#, т.к. при компиляции проекта с++, в методе GetSurfaces все данные в массиве list правильные.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: >>в методе GetSurfaces все данные в массиве list правильные<< Что значит правильные, и в чём тогда заключается вопрос?

Comment: @test123, в методе GetSurfaces проекта с++ все верно формируется, но когда вызываю этот метод из проекта c#, то поля структуры x,y,z с кривыми значениями, а простые int переменные id и count возвращаются в нормальном виде.

Comment: При этом id и count правильные? Вы ведь понимаете, что в данном случае: >>vector<mainRes> res = gObj->get_surfaces();<< - происходит конструктор копирования?

Comment: @test123, да, понимаю, но чем мне это мешает? Как это влияет на результат функции? Я ведь могу в конце функции эту копию очистить.

Comment: >>но чем мне это мешает?<< Это в тему оптимизации, раз уже настолько специфично всё перемешали. Не могли бы вы привести структуру mainRes?

Comment: @test123, добавила в описание вопроса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67874/discussion-between-test123-and-naf).

Comment: Могу ошибаться, давно забыл ++ но мне кажется что вектор это же контейнер и совсем не простой массив....